# move_uploaded_file saves on wrong destination

Tags: php, image, cakephp

I am trying to make this block of code to work:

```
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])){
        

        $nameImg = $this->request->getData()['imagem']['name'];
        $imgTmp = $this->request->getData()['imagem']['tmp_name'];

        $destination = "files\user\\".$user_id."\\".$nameImg;
        
        if(move_uploaded_file($imgTmp,WWW_ROOT . $destination)){
            $this->Flash->success(__('Success!'));
            

            }
        }
```

But every time i try to run it the image is saved on my webroot directory and not on my specified $destination path, all directories are set to 777 and move_uploaded_file returns true, what could i possibly do to make it save on the specified path?

And this is `$this->request->getData();`debug output:

```
[
    'imagem' => [
        'tmp_name' => '/tmp/phpTrcN6K',
        'error' => (int) 0,
        'name' => 'icone1.png',
        'type' => 'image/png',
        'size' => (int) 15778
    ]
]
```

Comment: Side note, **never use use unsanitized/unvalidated user input in `move_uploaded_file()`**! Passing `'name'` through `basename()` is the very minimum that should be done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use directory separator (DS) in your paths :

```
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])){
    $nameImg = $this->request->getData('imagem.name');
    $imgTmp = $this->request->getData('imagem.tmp_name');

    $destination = WWW_ROOT . 'files' . DS . 'user' . DS . $user_id . DS . $nameImg;
    
    if(move_uploaded_file($imgTmp, $destination)){
        $this->Flash->success(__('Success!'));
        }
    }
```